# Показ power point презентации в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Занимаюсь разработкой одной прилы, которая работает на движке unity. Появилась задача показывать слайды .pptx в сцене, но для этого нужно интегрировать презентацию в проект и как то отобразить каждый слайд.

Как можно показать слайды презентации в таком случае?

P.S. второй вариант это разбить презентацию на изображения, каждое отдельно друг от другу, но это должно так же делаться сразу в приложении, не прося об этом юзера и как это можно тогда сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Первый результат по запросу "unity ppt presentation" приводит к репозиторию:
https://github.com/UnityTechnologies/Presentation

Описание:

> This is an Editor extension for making and presenting slide decks in Unity. It allows you to easily mix static slides with interactive slides and in-editor demonstrations. Each slide is a Unity Scene which can work in or outside of Play Mode.

То есть это то что ты искал.

Comment: Да, это оно самое! Спасибо большое ! =)

Comment: Отметь вопрос как решенный. Галочка возле ответа который тебе помог.

Answer (score -1):

С помощью фреймворка майкрафсофт Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/vsto/powerpoint-solutions?view=vs-2019

Comment: Для использования Interop нужен установленный Office. Совет явно из вредных, если в его случае вообще рабочий. Неясно на какой платформе будет запускаться.